# Making two elements starting in the same html row

Tags: html, css, dom

I've got a small icon appearing and a sentence afterwards, in the next line. This code does so: (apart from more things)

```
<td class="workview-cell">
  {{#if isAvailable}}
    {{#if isLoaded}}
    A<img id="privileged-access-step-icon" src="{{urlRoot}}/images/crown16sb2.png"
         alt="test" title="test" />
    {{else}}
    B<img id="privileged-access-step-icon" src="{{urlRoot}}/images/crown16sb2.png"
         lt="test" title="test" />
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if showLink}}
    <a href="#" class="workview-link {{linkProperties.linkClass}} theme-link-color {{#if showLinkWideOnly}}wideonly{{/if}}"                     title="{{linkProperties.title}}">{{description}}</a>
    C{{#if showLinkWideOnly}}<span class="narrowonly">{{description}}</span>{{/if}}
  {{else}}
    {{description}}
  {{/if}}
</td>
```

The CSS associated is:

```
.workview-cell{padding:3px;vertical-align:middle;}
```

The rendered HTML is:

```
<td class="workview-cell">
  A<img id="privileged-access-step-icon" src="/images/crown16sb2.png" alt="Test" title="Test">                   
   <a href="#" class="workview-link viewstep-link theme-link-color " title="Open summary">Group Step (Initial)</a>
            B
    </td>
```

The string could break naturally across the rows, so I'd like to have the icon and the sentence afterwards as long as it can, finishing in the following line if the sentence is too large. In other words, I would rather the sentence started on the same line as the icon.

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

This is how it looks like right now:

[image: Text not starting in the same row where the icon is]

What I'd like to achieve is to have the text starting as soon as the icon finish, in the same line, and then continue if needed in the following line.

Comment: Always post only rendered HTML and a snippet with CSS too.

Comment: This is a CSS question

Comment: @PraveenKumar added HTML and CSS

Comment: @stackpepe Can you post an image and show what exactly is the problem? I am still not getting the issue.

Comment: @PraveenKumar image added, thanks

Comment: @stackpepe Answer added, you are welcome! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Give this CSS:

```
.workview-cell {white-space: nowrap;}
```

This forces the line to stay the same.

Comment: Indeed @PraveenKumar, many thanks for it, however the line doesn't continue in the following line. Any hint?

Comment: You said you don't wanna continue it in the following line right?

Comment: No, I said "What I'd like to achieve is to have the text starting as soon as the icon finish, in the same line, and then continue if needed in the following line.". Sorry if I have been unclear at any point

Comment: Quick fix, try giving `float: left` for both the image and text.

Comment: Should I use float:left in addition to white-space: nowrap ?

Comment: No no... Just `float: left`. And `overflow: hidden;` for the parent. @stackpepe...

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer, float:left and overflow:hidden is not working as well (It is just compressing everything to the left)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87396/discussion-between-stack-pepe-and-praveen-kumar).